# Facebook apps not like to have URL that not end with /

Tags: facebook, url

When creating new Apps i put on the canvas url 
http://www.mysite.com/folder/index.html

the apps not like it it say that it have to end with /
ex:
http://www.mysite.com/folder/index.html**/**

somehow my site don't like this url end with /
it throw me to my first page and i have to go to the specfic folder

on PHP site it works good

what is the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the canvas url to the folder, as such; http://www.mysite.com/folder/

Index.html should automatically be used if no file is specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put http://www.mysite.com/folder/index.php?number